# How to configure a javascript engine not to run the code if it contains IO or system setting related functions?

Tags: javascript

I just started using a javascript engine from Microsoft(of IE9?) for developing both desktop and browser applications. I'm looking for a javascript engine which you can configure so that it won't allow any script if it contains IO or system setting related functions.

Is there any one?

If yes, please let me know which and how to do that.For details. I must call non-compiled javascript string code from compiled code( C# or C++ or else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you can tweak the security settings in the v8 javascript engine! You should check out the embedders guide: http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html#security + I don't think it has I/O and System facilities unless you explicitly implement this in the C++ embedding code... This is how http://nodejs.org has done it.